# primsa model's column names with name of type number getting commented out after re-introspection even with valid @maps

Tags: prisma

I'm using mysql db, and have a table whose column names are 1, 2, 3...
Prisma doesn't support such column names, thus i changed my model to this

```
model dc_map {
  id           Int       @id @default(autoincrement()) @db.UnsignedInt
  region       String
  one          String    @map("1")
  two          String?   @map("2")
  three        String?   @map("3")
  four         String?   @map("4")
  five         String?   @map("5")
  six          String?   @map("6")
  seven        String?   @map("7")
  eight        String?   @map("8")
  nine         String?   @map("9")
  ten          String?   @map("10")
...
}
```

When i generate prisma client with these mappings, my queries run fine but as soon as i run 'prisma db pull', it commenents these mappings saying:

```
/// This field was commented out because of an invalid name. Please provide a valid one that matches [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*
  // one String @map("1")
  /// This field was commented out because of an invalid name. Please provide a valid one that matches [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*
  // two String? @map("2")..
```

and so on

where as my terminal says two different things,

```
These fields were enriched with @map information taken from the previous Prisma schema.
- Model "dc_map", field: "one"
- Model "dc_map", field: "two"
- Model "dc_map", field: "three"
- Model "dc_map", field: "four"
- Model "dc_map", field: "five"
- Model "dc_map", field: "six"
- Model "dc_map", field: "seven"
- Model "dc_map", field: "eight"
- Model "dc_map", field: "nine"
- Model "dc_map", field: "ten"

These fields were commented out because their names are currently not supported by Prisma. Please provide valid ones that match [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]* using the @map attribute.
- Model: "dc_map"
  Field(s): "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"
```

I'am currently using prima and prisma client version 4.8.0

I tried:

1. deleting node_modules and re-running npm i.
2. Restart VS Code, tried with another project with the same database, and faced same issue.
3. tried with downgrading my version from 4.8.0 to 4.6.1.

What I am expecting:
Prisma ideally should support anything as a mapped coulmn name which match [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*
maps like `one          String    @map("1")` work fine after client gets generated.
But i expect that it should not comment these mappings with warnings saying that those names are invalid

Comment: It looks like a bug, can you please open a GitHub Issue?
https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/new?assignees=&labels=kind%2Fbug&template=bug_report.yml

Comment: Do let me know in case you have created a GitHub Issue, I can share it internally